# Instantiate DeviceClient with IoT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a console app which sends commands directly to a Raspberry Pi via Azure IoT Hub. It all works fine.

Where I get confused though, is on the two different ways (possibly more?) to instantiate DeviceClient.

Ex:

```
    deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(IOT_HUB_HOST_NAME, AuthenticationMethodFactory
         .CreateAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(IOT_HUB_DEVICE, IOT_DEVICE_KEY), TransportType.Http1);
```

or

```
deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(IOT_HUB_CONN_STRING);
```

seem to do the same thing.

Why would I use one over the other? I can receive messages either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the end of the day they have the same result.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/csharp/device/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client/DeviceClient.cs

Create(...) method invokes IotHubConnectionStringBuilder.Create(...) then CreateFromConnectionString(...) and has the description that it is the method that creates DeviceClient from individual parameters.

So, i believe, the Create one is some kind of the wrapper that gets the parameters, then creates the connection string from the individual params and passes that to the CreateFromConnectionString(...). So, the main difference, i think, will be about the performance.